# Elemento 'configuration' não foi declarado

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

No `Web.config`, o problema ocorre na linha:

```
<configuration>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Error list: `Elemento 'configuration' não foi declarado.`

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solução:**

Ir no menu **XML** > **Esquemas...**

Procurar nome do arquivo de **DotNetConfig.xsd** e alterar para opção de `Usar este esquema`.

Aqui está a reposta original em inglês [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32116130/6647038).